# How to parse the output in powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0

The command `Get-Process` gives output like below:

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
     65       6     1152        840    59    77.50   6048 Appx
     78       8     2233        444    61    10.11   7878 Application
```

but I need a solution like below:

```
PM(K)=1152, ProcessName=Appx ; PM(K)=2233, ProcessName=Application
```

How do I parse output like above mentioned?

Comment: this is a result of `get-process` not `get-service`

Comment: @Kayasax yes, its get-process only. got updated the same in the above question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `-f` to format your string :

```
PS>$resu=""
PS>gps | foreach {$resu+=("PM(K)= {0},appName={1};" -f ($_.pm/1KB),$_.name) }
PS>$resu
```

Comment: you are right, its get-process only.

thanks u so much, its working like charming :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$p = Get-Process | select @{n='PM(K)';e={$_.PM/1KB}}, ProcessName
($p | fl | Out-String) -replace "`n`n", ' ; ' -replace "`n", ', '
```